# Java scientific calculator

Tags: java

Calculator

Objective: 
Create a scientific calculator.  It should behave like any other scientific calculator where the user presses keys and stuff happens.  This must have a graphical user interface (GUI), and include the following features:

Current total display
Number pad
Arithmetic functions
Addition
Subtraction
Multiplication
Division

You may disregard order of operations
Trigonometric functions
Sine
Cosine
Tangent
Arcsine
Arccosine
Arctangent

Additional mathematic functions
Exponent
Square root
Logarithm
Additional functions
Clear – Zeroes out the current total
Equals – Gives the running total

Furthermore every time a user enters a number first it should set the running total to said number.  If an operation is entered then that operation is applied to the current total.  If it is a binary operation like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and exponent then the following number will be the second number in that function, and applied as soon as the user presses equals.

how would you code this be coded? I've been searching and trying for hours now and I can't figure it out.

Comment: This question is not fit for Stack Overflow. Take the [tour] and read [ask] for future questions. This one will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem?

Just look for java examples of calculators and then incorporate the GUI.

By current total I think you mean current output till that step? After each step calculate the value and display it.

Comment: `java.lang.Math` can be used for the trigonometric functions.